# Migrate code 2.0 to 3.1 core code then swagger api versioning not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger

> Cannot implicitly convert type 
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,
> Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiPathItem>' to
> 'Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiPaths'
> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
public class ReplaceVersionWithExactValueInPath : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.Paths = swaggerDoc.Paths
            .ToDictionary(
                path => path.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version),
                path => path.Value
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `OpenApiDocument.Path` is not a dictionary
So you can't use the `swaggerDoc.Paths = swaggerDoc.Paths.ToDictionary()` assignment

try with new `OpenApiPath` object and `Add()` method

```cs
var oap = new OpenApiPaths();
foreach (var p in swaggerDoc.Paths)
    oap.Add(p.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version),
        p.Value);
swaggerDoc.Paths = oap;
```

Answer (score 0):

The type [`Microsoft.OpenApi.Models.OpenApiPaths`](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/3aeeef600d19e4ecfdf0d116725658b1c496eba0/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Models/OpenApiPaths.cs) inherits from the [`OpenApiExtensibleDictionary<OpenApiPathItem>`](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenAPI.NET/blob/3aeeef600d19e4ecfdf0d116725658b1c496eba0/src/Microsoft.OpenApi/Models/OpenApiExtensibleDictionary.cs) and than inherits from the [`Dictionary<string, OpenApiPathItem>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary__0__1__).

You can't use the `swaggerDoc.Paths = swaggerDoc.Paths.ToDictionary()`, but you can create new `OpenApiPaths` from the `IDictionary<string, OpenApiPathItem>`

```cs
var paths = new OpenApiPaths(swaggerDoc
              .Paths
              .ToDictionary(
                  path => path.Key.Replace("v{version}", swaggerDoc.Info.Version),
                  path => path.Value)
            );
swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
```